# ReadLine function for a file

Tags: c

I want the same functionality of readline but for a file. I don't want to pass a buffer and size. I'd like a method to malloc the right amount of space

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [`fgetc`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fgetc/), you can read a character at a time from a file.

Thus, you can create a function that reads a file line by line by calling `fgetc` several times. If a line is over, `fgetc` reads a `\n`. If the file is over, it reads `EOF`.

Now, you do the following: You create a `char line[1024]` (resp. a `char*` that is created via `malloc`) (or any other size) at the beginning, and fill it either one of the following is the case:

- `fgetc` gets `\n`: This means, that the current line is over, and you are done with this line.
- `fgetc` gets `EOF`: This means, that the whole file is over and you are completely done.
- `fgetc` gets anything else and there is still space available in `line`: Then you simply copy the char read into the appropriate position in `line`.
- `fgetc` gets anything else and `line` is already completely filled: Then, you [`realloc`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/realloc/) new memory for `line` and grow the current `line` (to be more specific, it is practical to double the size of `line` in this step).

So basically you need to inform yourself about `fgetc` and `realloc` and combine these two functions (and some auxiliary functions) to get what you want.

Comment: +1. But if you literally "create `char line[1024]`" you can hardly `realloc`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution I've used before.  It will read a line from a text file up to and including the newline.  It reads into a local, fixed-sized buffer first, and then appends that buffer to the result.

Reading ends when we see a newline or EOF or hit an error on input.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define PAGE_SIZE ...  // some size large enough to handle most cases

char *getLine(FILE *stream)
{
  char *res = NULL; 
  char inbuf[PAGE_SIZE];
  size_t len = 0;

  /**
   * We want to use strcpy the first time through the loop,
   * then strcat afterward.  Using a function pointer means
   * we don't have to execute a test each time through the 
   * loop.  For a sane text file where individual lines aren't
   * more than a few dozen characters long, this really doesn't
   * buy us anything over an if-else statement; I just think it's a cool trick.
   *
   * For C99, the prototype should be
   *
   *    char *(*f)(char * restrict, const char * restrict)
   */
  char *(*f)(char *, const char *) = strcpy;

  while (fgets(inbuf, sizeof inbuf, stream))
  {
    char *tmp = realloc(res, len + strlen(inbuf) + 1);
    if (tmp)
    {
      res = tmp;
      f(res, inbuf);
      f = strcat;
      len += strlen(inbuf) + 1;
    }
    if (strchr(inbuf, '\n'))
      break;
  }
  if (feof(stream))
    // hit EOF
  else
    // error on read; how you deal with it is up to you.
  return res;
}
```

Note that if we hit EOF or error on the initial read, the function will return `NULL`.

You will need to `free` each line when you're done with it.